# Comprehension list or map to improve performance?

Tags: python

Hello I'm trying to improve the performance of my code (find out a nice article here: http://leadsift.com/loop-map-list-comprehension/ )

And I'd like to know if I can use a comprehension list in this part of my code:

> ```
> for fmt in excels:
>     xls_list.add(fmt)
>     df_dict[fmt] = ''
> ```

Comment: Why do you think list comprehension will improve performance?

Comment: Because one action is appending elements to a list, maybe I can improve this functionality. In the other hand I'm creating new keys in my dict so I'm not pretty sure if it's a good idea or not.

Comment: A list comprehension can give a slight speed-up compared to a "traditional" `for` loop, but the difference isn't as great in Python 3. However, your code does not look suitable for a list (or other) comprehension.

Comment: Your code is readable, don't ruin it and attempt to "one-line" everything.

Comment: Ok thanks, for the advice. I will consider using comprehension list if I only have one loop appending elements.

Comment: What is `xls_list`? `list`s have no `.add()` method.

Comment: Python lists don't have an `.add` method, but sets do. Is `xls_list` actually a set? If you want to quickly create a dictionary from a sequence of keys, with all the values set to `''`, take a look at `dict.fromkeys`.

Comment: It's really a set because I want unique elements, but  after processing the file I cast set to list for making other operations.

Comment: Is `excels` a list as in my answer? because you need no iteration nor comprehension for that then. If not provide an example of `excels` with a low number of elements (2 at least)

Comment: Your title and body seem a bit inconsistent with each other. In regards to the title, have a read at [Python List Comprehension Vs Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).

Comment: Yes, @Adirio thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Reti43 Maybe it's a bit inconsistent, I'll take a look to that reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
excels = ['1.xls', '2.xls']
xls_list = set()
for fmt in excels:
    xls_list.add(fmt)
    df_dict[fmt] = ''
```

could be trasnformed into:

```
xls_list = set(excels)
df_dict = dict.fromkeys(excels, '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Please select the answer as accepted if it solved your problem so that the question appears as solved.